# How to add a physical file path to os.path.join?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cartopy

I am a beginner in Python and Jupyter noteboook,
I am trying to use Cartopy to plot the data I got from NOAA.
I got the code as below,
and what I am having issues is the "os.path.join" part,
as my data set is saved in my portable disc.
I tried to use the physical path and add that to the code I found.
But it showed me a "KeyError: '/Elements'"
The physical path is :
"/Elements/Capstone_Project_Data/NOAA/air.mon.amon.nc"

The code is as below:
Any suggestion and help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you very much!

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np

from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


# get the path of the file. It can be found in the repo data directory.
fname = os.path.join(config["/Elements"],'/Capstone_Project_Data','/NOAA',
                     #'/Elements','/Capstone_Project_Data','/NOAA',
                     'air.mon.amon.nc'
                     )

dataset = netcdf_dataset(fname)
sst = dataset.variables['sst'][0, :, :]
lats = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
lons = dataset.variables['lon'][:]

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.contourf(lons, lats, sst, 60,
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to adapt this example from the Cartopy documentation? https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html?highlight=config#contour-plots

In that example Cartopy's `config` dictionary is used to determine where some standard sample data is located. If you are providing your own data then there is no need to use the `config` dictionary at all, you can directly specify the path to the file, you maybe don't even need the `os.path.join` at all:

```
# Correct this if your path is different
fname = "/Elements/Capstone_Project_Data/NOAA/air.mon.mean.nc"
dataset = netcdf_dataset(fname)
```

(Note that if you use `os.path.join` it will insert the `/` for you so they don't need to prefix every element.)

The rest of the example will presumably not work because as it is written it is looking for the `sst` variable in the netcdf file, so you will have to change that to load the variable you are interested in from your file.

Comment: Thank you so much!! But this still threw me error: No such file or directory. I tried another like: fname = open('Volumes/Elements/Capstone_Project_Data/NOAA/air.mon.mean.nc', 'r'), no luck either.

Comment: Well, that just means there is no file at that location on your computer. You need to provide a path to the location of the file on your computer.

Comment: Thank you @ajdawson, I found that for some reasons the file disappeared after reading the file earlier. I fixed that now. Appreciated.